# Delphi: Cannot perform this operation on an open dataset

Tags: mysql, delphi, firemonkey, firedac

When I tried to use FireDAC FDQuery with MySQL database I got the following error:

```
Cannot perform this operation on an open dataset.
```

```
query.Open(....my connection string to MySQL....); 
try
    query.ExecSql;
finally
    query.Close;
```

I filled the FDQuery by double-clicking on the icon on the form. I also
connected to the database to test it. It gave back the results correctly.
I would like to use it from code, but it doesn't work, so
I debugged it. I always get to the breakpoint: query.Close;

Answer (score 7):

You can't call `Open` and `ExecSQL` on the same SQL, because they do different things.

Use `Open` when the query will return a result set, which means for a `SELECT`. Use `ExecSQL` when the query does **not** return a result set, which means for an `INSERT`, `DELETE` or `UPDATE`.

I can't tell you which one applies to your situation, because you failed to include your SQL in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about FireDAC specifically, but in general with these kind of database components, for queries not returning a result set, thus suitable for ExecSQL, you would want to use ExecSQL on the Connection object, in this case TFDConnection.  (Which would presumably be the Connection object that your FDQuery object is connected to.)
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Executing_Commands_(FireDAC)
Apparently there is an ExecSQL method on TFDCustomQuery, but I'm not sure why you would use that, and as you discovered, it doesn't work if the query is already in use.

Comment: The reason one would want to use a Query's ExecSQL is dependent on the complexity of the query. You may be in a situation where you don't want to build the query in your code (to pass to the TfdConnection.ExecSQL), it has multiple parameters, sub selections, etc.  Instead of having lots of lines of SQL code in a Delphi method, the TFDQuery object has them built in (especially when the query, itself, is static, but is complicated).  Just another tool to have available.

Comment: @JacalarRick  You seem to be describing a rationale for using Query's SQL property, not the ExecSQL method.

Comment: Yes and no.  Yes, since the purpose of using the TFDQuery is due to the need to use the SQL property.  But (the No) the query in the SQL doesn't have to return a dataset (TfdQuery.Open), but can just operate on the database (TfdQuery.ExecSQL).  The point being that whether one uses the TfdConnection's ExecSQL, or TfdQuery's ExecSQL is really a function of code management..  You state "why would you use that".

Comment: @JacalarRick  Ah, I see what you mean. I see in docs that a benefit to using a TFDQuery with .SQL and .ExecSQL (vs Connection's ExecSQL) is that you can use .Prepare to speed up multiple invocations. 
Side note: OP's code  "query.Open(....my connection string to MySQL....);" I think doesn't entirely make sense, as I don't see in the docs an overloaded version of Open that takes a connection string.  Anyhow, since in OP's code query.ExecSQL  has no argument, OP is perhaps just unaware that the Open statement already executes the SQL, and ExecSQL is not necessary in addition.